# Get data from selectors to input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, refresh

I am trying to make date picker same as facebook has but I need to get data to from it to hidden ... But my problem is, that I create it, but the data do not show up...
This is an easier reproduction:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="regform" name="regform" onMouseOut="refresh()">
  <script>
    function refresh(){
       $("#hiddenregdate").html(html);
    }
  </script>
  <select name="month" id="month">
    <option value="00" selected="selected">select...</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
  </select>
  <select name="day" id="day">
    <option value="00" selected="selected">select...</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
  </select>
  <select name="year" id="year">
    <option value="00" selected="selected">select...</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
   var day = $("#day").val();
   var month = $("#month").val();
   var year = $("#year").val();
   var date = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
   $("<input>").attr({
        value : date,
        id: "hiddenregdate",
        class : "hidden",
        type : "date",
        name : "regdate"
   })
```

**Do you have any idea where is the problem?**
I'm gonna ask somehow else... **How should I refresh only the "jQuery-created date input"?**

Comment: Observation: Use $("#day").find(':selected').val(); instead of $("#day").val();

Comment: I copied your code  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqagPo if anyone wants to pick it up.

Comment: Did not work... Says: Uncaught ReferenceError: html is not defined

Comment: Where did you defined HTML?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh nothing wrong with using `$('select').val()` No need to find the options

Comment: I did not define it, I think It's defined somewhere in source code of JS or jQuery but I don'T know I just tried what I found (amusingly) at StackOverFlow.... xD

Comment: @AdamOpalecký open browser dev tools (F12) and look at errors thrown in Console. `html is undefined` should show up, assuming no other errors prior to code reaching that point. Use those errors to figure out what is happening

Comment: I'll be sarcastic: No I did not try that! :O

Answer (score 0):

Where is your input tag on HTML?
You select element with tag input but you does not have any input tag on your HTML

try adding

```
<input>
```

on the html. And are you sure your JS doesn't missing a closing braces

Comment: thats wont create any tag. Thats just selecting tag input and add attribute to it. But you dont have any input tag.

Comment: I don't mean the JS in <script> tag but JS that is as code... Did you read all?

Answer (score 0):

## Never mind, I solved it somehow else (php)...

I deleted all JS and functions... I just made cookie:

```
$cbdate = $_POST["year"].$_POST["month"].$_POST["day"];
$EXD = time() + 30879000;
setcookie("bdate",$cbdate, $EXD, "/");
```